# Android Studio - Project structure is almost empty

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm on Android Studio 0.2.9 and when I open the Project Structure menu, well.. I've got **only** this :

[image]

**Modules menu and other things are no longer here** ! Does anyone experience this issue to ?
I think those topics are relative ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759613/import-external-library-in-android-studio-0-2-8) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793019/add-library-in-android-studio-0-2-8)).

**Edit :** Still getting this error in new version 0.2.10.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Me : "I have a bug". You : "Sometimes, there are bugs." Well, with that we'll improve all softwares in the world !

Comment: I had this problem last night after I updated. I fiddled with it some and eventually I got everything to come back. I really wish I could tell you what I did, but I honestly can't tell you (may have reimported my project). I think this is a new bug introduced in 0.29. Glad it wasn't just me.

Comment: I have this problem too. I tried re-importing and that didn't solve it. Any other guesses as to what you did to fix it Dopyiii?

Comment: I'm having this problem in Android Studio 0.2.10, even when I create a new project.

Comment: This answer seems to provide a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18759925/382892

Comment: Don't forget that you can [report bugs in Android Studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, somebody reported this "issue" on google project here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60310.

As you can see, google team answer is :

> The other panels are not relevant for **Gradle projects** and are **being hidden**, except for occasional bugs where they unexpectedly reappear.

So I tried to import **an old project without Gradle** and here is what the Project Structure looks like now, on Android Studio v0.2.11 :

[image]

To summarize, **Android Studio hides some Project Settings when the project is managed with Gradle** (in order to not mix library file import without Gradle, probably..).

Feel free to comment if I'm wrong, but it seems to work this way now.