# Android Studio - Importing libraries to a gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I imported a gradle project from eclipse and I'd like to add some libraries to the project.

The usual approach would be to import a module in the Project Structure window.

The problem is that according to google I can't do that with a gradle project: [Android Studio - Project structure is almost empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877728/android-studio-project-structure-is-almost-empty)

If so, in what way that is compatible with gradle projects can I import a library?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the project window, right click on your project name and new a directory named 'libs'. libs has the same level of build and src.
2. Copy your jar file to libs within file manager of OS.
3. Wait for seconds, the jar file will show under libs in android studio. Right click on it and click 'add as library'.
4. Add info to build.gradle, for example

   ```
   dependencies {  
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'  
       compile files('libs/NameOfYourFile.jar')  
   }
   ```
5. Now, you can use the library and build. If you get some errors, Enter project directory and run `./gradlew clean` and rebuild your project.